# Can't identify elements after ajax insert

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

There is a data in Django DB, when html page loaded it sends request to db and create html block in Django template, and at last it insert to html by id. This part works, checkboxes creates and all is good, but there is no elements if I try to find them by id after ajax insert.

How to to get access them?

html:

```
<div id="fill-statuses" status-table-url="{% url 'ajax_status_data' %}"></div>
```

Django template:

```
{% for status in statuses %}
<label class="toggle">
        <input class="toggle__input" type="checkbox" id="{{ status.status_new }}_status_check_box">
        <span class="toggle__label">
          <span class="toggle__text">{{ status.status_new }}</span>
        </span>
      </label>
{% endfor %}
```

view.py:

```
def fill_status_check_boxes(request):
    statuses = TaskStatus.objects.values('status_new').distinct

    return render(request, 'persons/statuses_for_filter.html', {'statuses': statuses})
```

And now js block, with comments:

```
function fill_status_check_boxes() {
  const url = $("#fill-statuses").attr('status-table-url')
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#fill-statuses').html(data)
    },
      complete: function () {
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id*='status_check_box']")) //return array with elements, that's why I thought that all works, when tested it
      }
  })
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id*='status_check_box']")) //but here return empty array []
}

fill_status_check_boxes()

console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id*='status_check_box']")) //and here also return empty array []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax()` is executed asynchronously

So that's why your `console.log` inside the `complete` callback display what you're expecting, instead of the one after the ajax call.

You can create a new function to call on complete :

```
function fill_status_check_boxes() {
  const url = $("#fill-statuses").attr('status-table-url')
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#fill-statuses').html(data)
    },
      complete: handleComplete
  })
}

fill_status_check_boxes()

function handleComplete() {
    // Do some stuffs
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id*='status_check_box']"))
}
```

Comment: so tell him the fix 

Comment: Yes, here's the fix in edited answer :)

Comment: @GregThB, thanks, its fix one part of my problem!)
Is there any way to use elements by querySelectorAll("[id*='status_check_box']") in other functions? 

I create this checkboxes and after that I want to work with them in different ways

Comment: At the end of the handleComplete function you can dispatch a Javascript event in order to tell other javascript functions the ajax call has been proceeded completely :
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events to see more about Events and perform your feature :)

Comment: @GregThB, great! I will go to read documentation. Thank you!